# How to avoid polymorphism?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a data type `OperationSequence`. Below is OperationSequence.h

```
class OperationSequence
{
public:
    void appendOperation(std::function<double(double)> operation);
    void moveOperation(int operation_index);
    void eraseOperation(int operation_index);

    const std::vector<std::function<double(double)>>& data() const;
private:
    std::vector<std::function<double(double)>> operation_sequence;
};

double executeSequence(const OperationSequence& operation_sequence, double value);
void executeSequence(const OperationSequence& operation_sequence, const std::string& file_name);
```

I have to implement `printOperationSequence(const OperationSequence& operation_sequence).`

Assignment set a requirement on operation to be `f: double -> double`. Some operations like `Addition` and `Multiplication` were also requested.
Obvious implementation would be to create an Interface `Operation` and have it be callable with `f: double -> double` and have a `std::string getName()` method.

What would be a good way for OperationSequence to remain this generic but also making it easy and efficient to print out OperationSequence in a meaningful way?

Meaningful way being something like Multiplication, Addition, ...

Is delegating construction to some other class that will also create a operation_name_sequence a good idea?

P.S. Feel free to improve the question title :D

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to avoid polymorphism? Your assignment seems like a great use-case for it.

Comment: Mostly curiosity. Some of it being impressed with Stepanov, and i've heard him something like: "I have nothing against virtual functions, I just haven't had the need to use them".

Comment: Check the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and static polymorphism, or type traits if that helps for your needs.

Comment: Curiosity is a good driver, and a good reason for doing something differently (at least in academic circles). But don't forget that polymorphism exists, and in most cases are really useful. The hardest lesson is to know the few cases when it's useful to *not* use it.

Comment: Also, should operation really be required to have a name? It doesnt seem like a natural requirement on it. I obviously need it for printing, but also it would "smell" to me to replace this f: double -> double requirement with something stronger.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid to have polymorphism (even if `std::function` uses it or similar for type erasure), you might create class `Operation` to add name to the function:

```
struct Operation
{
    std::string name;
    std::function<double(double)> f;
};

class OperationSequence
{
public:
    void appendOperation(const Operation& operation);
    void appendOperation(const std::string& name, std::function<double(double)> f);

    void moveOperation(int operation_index);
    void eraseOperation(int operation_index);

    const std::vector<Operation>& data() const;
private:
    std::vector<Operation> operations;
};
```

then

```
void printOperationSequence(const OperationSequence& operation_sequence)
{
    for (const auto& op : operation_sequence.data()) {
         std::cout << op.name << std::endl;
    }
}
```